# jquery function doesn't work after typing in textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $('.quote').live('click', function() {


    var quote = "test";
    $("#msg").append(quote).scrollTop($('#msg')[0].scrollHeight).focus();

 });
```

This function just copies "test" to the textbox. Since it will be a multi-quote function I used the append() function. It works fine. Even when I focus on the textbox.

BUT when I type any characters in the textbox or break the line it no longer works. Any ideas?

msg - textbox

focus(); isn't also working for some reason.

Comment: I think you'd be better off updating the **value** of the textbox instead of treating it as an HTML container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
$("#msg").val(function(index, value) {
    return value + ' ' + quote;
}).scrollTop($('#msg')[0].scrollHeight).focus();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qgRuy/)